# Minimisation of ||Ax|| with sparse x, ||x||=1

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I need a bit of help finding search terms, keywords, or ideally even code that can be used to help me find a viable solution to the following minimisation problem.

$$^{min}_{\:\:x}\: |Ax|_2 \:\:s.t.\: |x|_2 = 1, $$
$$\:density(x)<<length(x)$$

My problem involves a large number (~100) of data types, with an even larger number of data points (~ between 500 - 2,000), that create a real matrix $A$ that is $m \mathbb{x} n$ with $m>n$. In order to avoid over-fitting, I'm looking for a vector $x$ of size $n$ that has only a few non-zero terms.

I've noted that Total Least Squares methods might be viable, but all the papers I've found on Sparse TLS solving use an equation of the form $Ax=b$, and I worry that as my $b$ term is zero, this may prove to cause issues in any implementation I attempt.

**notes on A:** *A is not sparse. A does not have a kernel. A is an Alternant matrix of lipschitz continuous functions on a fairly fine grid. Each column of A has magnitude equal to the length of that column.*

Answer (score 1):

You could try solving the regularized problem:

\begin{align}
\min~~&\|Ax\|_2 + \lambda\|x\|_1\\[1mm]
\text{s.t.}~~& \|x\|_2 = 1
\end{align}

where $\lambda$ is some nonzero scalar. The addition of the $1$-norm term $\|x\|_1$ tends to induce sparsity in the solution. The scalar $\lambda$ controls the importance of the regularization term. You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) - look under the section Regularizers for sparsity. If $A$ is not too large then you can check how close you are to the optimal non-sparse solution $(\lambda = 0)$ by computing the singular values of $A$ and comparing with $\sigma_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't dictate sparseness of a solution of a minimization problem?!

E.g. if the minimization problem would be the maximum absolute value of $x_i$, the solution would be something with all $x_i$ equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$

Unless you are willing to sacrifice optimality for sparseness, then you could fiddle with your optimization algorithm, e.g. add a cost function for non-zero elements in $x$. I'm not sure how to do that in your case.

Comment: You actually can. A really basic example would simply be to perform the minimization for all possible groups of $k$ collumns of $A$, and see which one produces the smallest $ |Ax|_2$, however, this is intractable. We have algorithms like LASSO that do things in a much more efficient way for least squares regression. (Here's a toolbox that contains a matlab implementation of LASSO: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/spasm/)

I know that algorithms do exist to do this for TLS problems, however, they aren't free, so I would have to build it myself, and I want to be certain first that this works.

Comment: OK, but indeed you are sacrificing optimality for sparseness in my example. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ is larger than the optimal solution..

Comment: Yes, but your example has nothing to do with sparse systems. In fact it's literally the opposite of a sparse system, it's an entierly dense system.